# Pass lookup value from one to another

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-4, lookup

In order to pass one datatime field to another I do this:

```
DynamicEntity leadEntity = new DynamicEntity(EntityName.lead.ToString());               
CrmDateTime modifiedby = (CrmDateTime)myImage.Properties["modifiedby"];
CrmDateTimeProperty dtAssignedBy = new CrmDateTimeProperty
                (
                    "new_assignedbyid",
                    modifiedby
                );
leadEntity.Properties.Add(dtAssignedBy);
```

How do I do the same for lookups?
if 'modifiedby' and 'new_assignedbyid' were lookups, how can I pass the chosen value of

Comment: Which version of CRM? 4 or 2011?

Answer (score 0):

The following link has a good overview

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb959615.aspx

There are two main properties - value and type which must be set for the lookup to be valid.

So you could do something like:

```
var modifiedby = (Lookup)myImage.Properties["modifiedby"];
var new_modifiedby = new Lookup();
new_modifiedby.value = modifiedby.value;
new_modifiedby.type = modifiedby.type;
```

Although you could probably just as easily do

```
var new_modifiedby = (Lookup)myImage.Properties["modifiedby"];
```

But I haven't verified that one.